# canopy matplotlib windows 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, canopy

I've tried to run matplotlib in canopy on windows 7 64bit. After updating the packages in canopy it does not work the matplotbib. My numpy version installed showed in package manager is 1.8.0-2. Help needed with this problem. matplotlib version installed 1.3.1.-3
I've run an example code of an animation from website of matplotlib.org.
The error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

H:\Nauka\nowy.py in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import matplotlib.animation as animation
      4 
      5 def update_line(num, data, line):

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 import matplotlib
---> 24 import matplotlib.colorbar
     25 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
     26 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 29 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     30 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     31 import matplotlib.contour as contour

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in <module>()
     21 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     22 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 23 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     24 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     25 from matplotlib import _path

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in <module>()
     48 
     49 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 50 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     51 from matplotlib.path import Path
     52 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in <module>()
     12 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     13 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
---> 14 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
     15 import matplotlib.dviread as dviread
     16 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

C:\Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py in <module>()
     60 
     61 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
---> 62 import matplotlib._png as _png
     63 ####################
     64 

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update to Canopy 1.4.0, then quit Canopy, delete
 `C:Users\HOT-GAZ\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User` 
and restart Canopy.